# Language Puzzle

Tags: grammatical-number

Back in the 1980s I caught part of a radio morning show, when a linguistic puzzle was asked, but which I never heard the answer to, because it was revealed later in the day when I was at school. The question has perplexed me since then. Basically, it goes like this: "Which English word has the property that removal of the last letter makes the word plural?"
If anyone can figure this out and post the answer, that would be great!

Comment: *plural**s***....

Comment: The full OED defines ***specie*** as *Species; kind*. But they qualify that with *now **obsolete**, except as **erroneous** singular of **species***.

Comment: **Necropolis** is the answer I've found, although not all dictionaries contain the plural **necropoli**.  The OED also has **metropoli** as a plural of **metropolis**, but I don't know if that's still current.  There are actually quite a few possible answers to the riddle - I saw a list of them somewhere once.

Comment: [“Isn't **peni** the plural of **penis**?” “I don't know,” says Cindy. “It should be if it's from Latin. Amicus amici. Cactus cacti. Penis peni.”](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22peni+the+plural%22)

Comment: @rjpond: A search for our first two suggestions + ***quiz*** led me to [this discussion](http://steiner.math.nthu.edu.tw/usr3/math2-backup/puzzle/language). Haven't read much, but ***metamorphosis*** leapt out at me.

Comment: The obvious answer would be **any third person singular present form of a non-modal verb** (e.g., singular _follows_ -> plural _follow_). Also, from @Fumble’s link _caress_ -> _cares_ is good—the puzzle didn't say it had to be the word’s _own_ plural, after all. The rest are obscure, incorrect, or archaic variants, like the _metropoli_ or _peni_ examples.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network (Puzzling SE, if I remember correctly).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - OP’s has phrased the question, .”.. makes the word plural.” I read that has it must be its own plural or Dan Bron’s solution- which I kinda like.

Comment: @Jim That is indeed the reading that would most immediately spring to mind—but there's really nothing in the wording itself that requires it to be so. “Makes it plural” can just as well be interpreted to only mean “makes it a plural word”, which I suspect is the twist the puzzler intended.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I’d agree if it said, “makes it plural” and given how long ago it was, it could very well have been so in the original, but the ***the*** in this question’s phrasing doesn’t allow that in my opinion.

Comment: @Jim Well, “_the_ word” is the word that you’re talking about. If you remove the final s from _caress_ to make _cares_, “the word” still refers to the thing you’ve written out on a peace of paper; the word was _caress_, now it’s _cares_. Take away another letter and it becomes _cars_, but it’s still “the word”. Whether you use the full noun phrase or a pronoun doesn’t really matter. “Removal of the last letter makes the word a plural word” works just as well.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

I know of three:

- caress
- princess
- timeliness

Answer (score 0):

Delving into my memories I think I know the answer you missed for **a singular English word which becomes plural if you remove the final "s"**. The trick is that the singular is not related to the plural.

> CARESS

As others have pointed out, there are alternatives, but I think I also heard that broadcast *and* caught the answer (maybe I played hookey :-)

And while I typed, Scott has beaten me (well done Scott!)